# performance difference between to_char and to_date

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have simple SQL query.. on Oracle 10g. I want to know the difference between these queries:

```
select * from employee where id = 123 and 
          to_char(start_date, 'yyyyMMdd') >= '2013101' and 
          to_char(end_date, 'yyyyMMdd') <= '20121231';

select * from employee where id = 123 and 
          start_date >= to_date('2013101', 'yyyyMMdd') and 
          end_date <= to_date('20121231', 'yyyyMMdd');
```

Questions: 
1. Are these queries the same? start_date, end_date are indexed date columns. 
2. Does one work better over the other?

Please let me know. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter is almost certain to be faster.

- It avoids data type conversions on a column value.
- Oracle will estimate better the number of possible values between two dates, rather than two strings that are representations of dates.

Note that neither will return any rows as the lower limit is probably *intended* to be higher than the upper limit according to the numbers you've given. Also you've missed a numeral in 2013101.

Answer (score 2):

One of the **biggest flaw** when you converting, casting or transforming to expression (i.e. "NVL", "COALESCE" etc.) **columns** in **WHERE clause** is that **CBO will not be able to use index on that column**. I slightly modified your example to show the difference:

```
SQL> create table t_test as
  2    select * from all_objects;
Table created
SQL> create index T_TEST_INDX1 on T_TEST(CREATED, LAST_DDL_TIME);
Index created
```

Created table and index for our experiment.

```
SQL> execute dbms_stats.set_table_stats(ownname => 'SCOTT',
                                        tabname => 'T_TEST',
                                        numrows => 100000,
                                        numblks => 10000);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

We are making CBO think that our table kind of big one.

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select *
  3    from t_test tt
  4   where tt.owner = 'SCOTT'
  5     and to_char(tt.last_ddl_time, 'yyyyMMdd') >= '20130101'
  6     and to_char(tt.created, 'yyyyMMdd') <= '20121231';
Explained
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2796558804
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |        |     3 |   300 |  2713   (1)| 00:00:33 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T_TEST |     3 |   300 |  2713   (1)| 00:00:33 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Full table scan is used which would be costly on big table.

```
SQL> explain plan for
  2  select *
  3    from t_test tt
  4   where tt.owner = 'SCOTT'
  5     and tt.last_ddl_time >= to_date('20130101', 'yyyyMMdd')
  6     and tt.created <= to_date('20121231', 'yyyyMMdd');
Explained
SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1868991173
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |              |     3 |   300 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T_TEST       |     3 |   300 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T_TEST_INDX1 |     8 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See, now it's index range scan and the cost is significantly lower.

```
SQL> drop table t_test;
Table dropped
```

Finally cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

for output (displaying) purpose use to_char

for "date" handling (insert, update, compare etc) use to_date

I don't have any performance link to share, but using to_date in above Query should run faster!

While the to_char it will first cast the date and then for making the compare it will need to resolve it as date type. There will be a small performance loss.

As using to_date it will not need to cast first, it will use date type directly.